# How I can find matching data row in Mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Been beating my head around trying to find a single query that will find matching rows.

**I have this table called likes:**

```
id|UserId|LikeUserId|Date|
```

**Query to retrieve everyone who likes me:**

```
SELECT * FROM ve_wholikes l 
JOIN ve_users u ON l.UserId=u.UserId 
WHERE l.LikeUserID = '$loginid_session'
```

**Query to retrieve everyone I like:**

```
SELECT * FROM ve_wholikes l 
JOIN ve_users u ON l.LikeUserId=u.UserId 
WHERE l.UserID = '$loginid_session'
```

What would be the query to find out every row that match (I like them & they like me)?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and tell us why it failed?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: I have no idea what query I should write. Im beating my head on walls trying to find a solution. I thought about maybe using "mysql_num_rows" to count or something... I don't know

Comment: `WHERE l.LikeUserID = '$loginid_session' AND l.UserID = '$loginid_session'` What happens when you try that?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Tried that. Returns an empty result where it should return at least 1 row.

Comment: Have you tried a LEFT JOIN? Honestly we cannot answer this without seeing how the tables are configured and a sampling of the data. You might think about setting up a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the `ve_wholikes` table to itself on `UserId = LikeUserId` and vice versa to find mutual likes.

```sql
SELECT l1.*, u.* FROM 
ve_wholikes l1
INNER JOIN ve_wholikes l2 ON l1.UserId = l2.LikeUserId AND l1.LikeUserId = l2.UserId
INNER JOIN ve_users u ON l1.LikeUserId = u.UserId
WHERE l1.UserId = ?;
```

The  records from the `ve_users` table will be the users that liked you. I just selected one of the `ve_wholikes` tables. You could select columns from `l2` as well if you need to see the date when they liked you back.